# How to break a loop with the same key sent by the loop?

Tags: loops, autohotkey, hotkeys, auto

Recently I've decided to code a faster auto clicker, but, while making it, I've run into a bit of a problem with the way I would like to break the loop. The way I have this auto clicker set up, is that it is only to activate when both mouse 5 and mouse 1 are pressed. I have it made to be broken when a button is released, but then the problem is the key release that breaks it is mouse 1. Obviously the easiest fix would to have it be broken by release of mouse 5, but due to both preference and stubbornness, I would rather the loop be broken by releasing mouse 1. In short, I'd like to have the loop continue running while mouse 5 is released, but not while mouse 1 is released. I hope that made sense, sorry if I've worded some things strangely.

Now, being new to AHK, more specifically things like this, I do not exactly know how to accomplish this goal. My code is below, and is a somewhat modified version of the OP of [this post's](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/47p78q/how_to_make_a_fast_clicker_7001500_cps/) code.

```
setmousedelay 0 
setbatchlines 0
Count = 0
Stop = 0
Return

Xbutton2 & LButton::
    ST := A_TickCount 
    Loop  
    {
        Click
        If Not GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
        break
    }

Return

f1::
ExitApp
```

I don't believe that `ST := A_TickCount` is necessarily needed, since I believe it server the purpose of counting the CPS (from the OP), but regardless I've decided to leave it in just in case.

As always, thank you for taking the time to read my post, I appreciate any and all answers/replies. My use of terminology and english are sometimes pretty poor, so if there's something I've left confusing, please feel free to ask me about it.

Comment: Would you mind posting your code as well? It will also make your explanation easier to understand.

Comment: The code that is in this post is mine, not the one I found on Reddit. What is it that you are confused on? Edit: oh yes if you're confused on what I mean by the whole releasing stuff, I mean I want it to be a hold toggle.

Comment: Ah, when you mentioned "mouse 5" and "mouse 1" I thought you were referring to `XButton5` and `XButton1` instead of `XButton2` and `LButton`.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I'm used to calling them mouse1 from csgo and other source games.

Comment: Mouse5 is called XButton2 in AHK. And the code in the post should work as expected (first holding XButton2 and then holding mouse1 gets it going, at that point you're able to release XButton2 and the clicker keeps going until you release mouse1). If you're not experiencing the expected behavior, then it's about something else. Where are you testing it?

Comment: Hm. You're correct, and I feel very stupid. This is the second auto clicker I have and the other one is bound to the exact same buttons. I'm speechless.